# ListBox layout with some kind of Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox

I have this data coming from a XML:

```
var searched = from c in xml.Descendants("tbody").Descendants("tr")
         let team = c.Element("td").ElementsAfterSelf("td")
         select new Time
            {
                a = c.Element("td").ElementsAfterSelf("td").First().Value,
                b = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(3).Value),
                c = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(4).Value),
                d = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(5).Value),
                e = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(6).Value),
                f = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(7).Value),
                g = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(8).Value),
                h = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(9).Value),
                i = Int32.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(10).Value),
                j = float.Parse(c.Descendants("td").ElementAt(11).Value)
            };
```

Done this, I'm displaying them in a `ListBox`:

```
foreach (var item in searched)
    {
         listBox1.Items.Add(item.a + "  " + item.b + "  " + item.c + "  " + 
           item.d + "  " + item.e + "  " + item.f  + "  " + item.g + "  " + 
           item.h + "  " + item.i + "  " + item.j);
         listBox1.Items.Add("  ");
    }
```

It prints fine, that's how I wanted it.
Now I need to format it.
Now, it is printing like this:

```
a     b    c    d  e  f  g  h  j
```

However, the variable's content differs in size. So the information do not get very organized.
So I wanted something like:


a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|j

a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|j


In which the | represents a column. I was thinking about a grid inside a list box but then I got lost on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what about a ListBox with an `ItemTemplate` tailored to your data?

This is the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding a}" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding b}" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding c}" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It uses a grid for each item, putting the values in separate columns. You can experiment with the column sizes.

This demonstrates the binding:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
    list.Add(new MyObject() { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 });
    list.Add(new MyObject() { a = 4, b = 57346, c = 6 });
    list.Add(new MyObject() { a = 7, b = 8, c = 9 });

    listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

I just create a list with made-up data and set it as `ItemsSource` of the list box. In your case the data will come from the XML.

And I used this mock class for testing:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```

It only has 3 fields for demonstrating how it works. You can easily add the other fields as well. For each additional field add one additional `ColumnDefinition` and `TextBlock` in the XAML and set the `Binding` accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! I was really thinking about a grid inside a listbox but I was missing the <grid.ColumnDefinitions>...
Thk you, the data now is a LOT more organized!
One thing... The    <ColumnDefinition> inside    <grid.ColumnDefinitions> is required everytime I want to add a column?

Comment: Yes, every `<ColumnDefinition>` gives a column which can then be referenced via `Grid.Column = "x"` to put controls there.